# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: java, android

Tenho esse erro quando clico em um item do RecyclerView e passo um objeto pela Intent, já implementei Serializable e não funcionou

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProcedimentoViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //Populando o Procedimento com o item na posição selecionada
        final Procedimento procedimento = mFilter.getProcedimentoFilter().get(position);
        //Setando as informações do adapterLayout na lista
        //holder é a o valor que o metodo onCreateViewHolder retorna, no caso a view com a referencia dos componentes
        viewHolder.titulo.setText(procedimento.getTitulo());
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(procedimento);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap<String, Procedimento> mapProcedimento = new HashMap<String, Procedimento>();
                mapProcedimento.put("Procedimento", procedimento);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProcedimentoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mapProcedimento", mapProcedimento);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }





05-19 14:57:24.058 2994-2994/com.basedeconhecimento E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.basedeconhecimento, PID: 2994
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.basedeconhecimento.Modelo.Procedimento@35c8dce
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1477)
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:698)
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:682)
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1389)
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
                                                                                    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
                                                                                    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
                                                                                    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8687)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4522)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4490)
                                                                                    at com.stefanini.basedeconhecimento.Adapter.ProcedimentoAdapter$1.onClick(ProcedimentoAdapter.java:71)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Quem puder ajudar , muito obrigado

Comment: Michael, pq precisa passar um mapa para a outra Activity, tem alguma razão específica? Minha sugestão é passar o objeto direto no Extras. Além disso, a classe `Procedimento` implementa Parcelable ou Serializable?

Answer (score -1):

Todos os objetos da classe Collections implementam o Serializable. Então, provavelmente o erro está na implementação da interface serializable da classe Procedimento.